# Email sent by SAP Workflow has partial Web hyperlink

Tags: workflow, sap-basis, sapconnect

I think this might be a simple question but I cannot seem to figure it out.
I have a workflow which simply sends a mail. In the content of the mail I
have a hyperlink going back to our SAP CRM system. I pass some parameters to this hyperlink.

The workflow works fine and the email is sent, however, the hyperlink goes onto the second line of the mail and becomes in active. If I copy the entire hyperlink and paste it in a browser it works.

The issue is I don't want users to copy and paste, I simply want them to click on the hyperlink.

Here is a screen print of what I am talking about 
http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/9471/38348167.png

And here is a screen print of the actual email that is sent: 
http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/6424/14370746.png

I tried going into transaction PFTC (Task Maintain) I entered my task and opened it up. I went to the tab description
and hit the edit button and I changed the tag column to continuous text but that didnt work, and then I tried extended line
and that too didn't make a difference.

Here is a screen shot of that:
http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/6254/37776438.png

My question is, is there any way to get the hyperlink on one line or even to have it be clickable on 2 lines?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, that's a limitation of SAPconnect when sending plain-text emails. You could reconfigure the system to send HTML mails, but this would affect EVERY outgoing mail and should be handled extremely cautious. I'd suggest you write a small class to assemble and send the HTML mail and call it from the step. I'd use the BCS for sending the mail - it has an [excellent online documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/aa/29673a9011fc7be10000000a11402f/frameset.htm) and comes with several demo programs (BCS_EXAMPLE_*). You could assemble the HTML body using ABAP, although this usually yields rather messy code. Cleaner ways of ding this would be to either put all of the input data into a structure and use a simple transformation or dynamic documents (see for example report DD_ADD_LINK).